# Chart.js multiTooltip labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to get charts.js to display the label name from each dataset in the tooltip.

My code:

```
var barChartData = {
    labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
    datasets : [

        {
            label: "Bob",
            fillColor : "rgba(88,196,246,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(88,196,246,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(88,196,246,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(88,196,246,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            label: "Tina",
            fillColor : "rgba(74,211,97,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(74,211,97,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(74,211,97,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(74,211,97,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }

    ]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(barChartData, {
    responsive : true,
    animation: true,
    barValueSpacing : 5,
    barDatasetSpacing : 1,
    tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",                
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= label %> - <%= value %>"

});
```

With my above code the tooltip when hovering above "January" displays:

```
January
January - xx
January - xx
```

Any ideas how I can get it to display the following?

```
January
Bob - xx
Tina - xx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How put dataset labels into multiTooltipTemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278167/how-put-dataset-labels-into-multitooltiptemplate)

Answer (score 134):

Change

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(barChartData, {
   responsive : true,
   animation: true,
   barValueSpacing : 5,
   barDatasetSpacing : 1,
   tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",                
   multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= label %> - <%= value %>"
});
```

to:

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(barChartData, {
   responsive : true,
   animation: true,
   barValueSpacing : 5,
   barDatasetSpacing : 1,
   tooltipFillColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",                
   multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
});
```

The change is to the last line

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
```

`datasetLabel` gets the value of the label from the dataset objects (in this case 'Bob' and 'Tina'), whereas `label` gets the caption printed on the x-axis (part of the `labels` array)

Comment: It would be ideal if you could highlight the changes made, and why said changes are necessary to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it possible (how) to use HTML inside? As used in legendTemplate (documentation) but seems not to work with multiTooltipTemplate

Comment: The [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) does not even state the `datasetLabel` parameter! Annoying! It took me hours to find a solution, this answer save me another hour. Thanks!

Comment: I have been looking for this for hours. As John said, the documentation doesn't even state it!

Comment: Are there any other variables like `datasetLabel` available to use inside the template?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js#L3155 . Not sure about the x/y values always being available though.

Comment: I am so confused.  Where did the ruby come from?  I tried doing this in rails and as expected i'm getting an object undefined error.

Comment: Great answer. This part of the Chart.js documentation is severely lacking.

Comment: Is it possible to format also the title of the multitoolTemplate? i.e., the x-axis value showing as title in the tooltip.

Comment: @daao87 tooltipTitleTemplate can be used to format the title of the multiTooltipTemplate.

Answer (score 10):

want to update the answer, because I was searching for a long time.

You can now change the tooltips settings inside the options. See Docu:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration

As for the asked question, to show all X data.

```
window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Line(barChartData, {
  tooltips: {
   mode: 'label'
 }           
});
```

Cheers
Hannes

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If this isn't working for you label mode is now deprecated - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34893529/1994542), you can give multiTooltipTemplate a function. Put a breakpoint inside that function with 'debugger', and explore the given object for all the properties you'd like. Then construct a string to be displayed in your tooltip:

```
multiTooltipTemplate: function(v) {debugger; return someManipulation(v);}
tooltipTemplate: function(v) {return someOtherManipulation(v);}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer by Hannes but the documentation has been updated since then - There are various options now and the link he provided no longer goes anywhere as that option is deprecated.

I'm adding a new answer as it took me a while to find.

This is x mode - displays multiple dataset info in tooltip based on x axis

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'x'
        }
    }
})
```

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#x

There is also 'y' mode. Label mode is now deprecated.

You can also use 'point', 'index' and 'nearest' mode.