# ChartJS: How to get labels, legend, title to show up?

Tags: chart.js

I'm having a tough time figuring out how to get labels, legend and title showing up in my Chart JS Line Chart. I've copied the code directly from the [example](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart) (reproduced below). However, the label "My First dataset" doesn't show up anywhere on the chart and so I can't tell which line is which. I've also tried adding a 'title' to my datasets, but with no luck. Anyone know what I'm missing?

```js
    var data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
            label: "My Second dataset",
            fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
            strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
            pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
            pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
    ]};
```

Thanks,
Saswat

Comment: I'm also unable to get the Labels to show up when using the default code.  To access the Legend, I'm doing this:

$(element).parent().append( myNewChart.generateLegend() );

(where myNewCart is the variable I used when creating the chart.

Comment: Another comment. After distilling it down and creating a fiddle, the labels do show up as expected, so for me there must be some other code that is interfering.  I can't imagine what it could be though, the relevant code in my production site is exactly the same as my fiddle, yet in the fiddle the labels show.  Hrmmmm...

Comment: I suppose that the solution you are looking for has been answered another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510278/chart-js-multitooltip-labels Regards Lucas

Comment: might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510278/chart-js-multitooltip-labels

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How put dataset labels into multiTooltipTemplate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278167/how-put-dataset-labels-into-multitooltiptemplate)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

in the option add this parameter

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>"
```

Comment: Stuck with issue similar to this. Kindly help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279205/how-to-display-sign-on-mouse-hover-in-pie-chart

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer