# How put dataset labels into multiTooltipTemplate?

Tags: chart.js

There is a color of current `dataset` element, but how can I put current `dataset` label into `tooltip`, exchange for label from xAxis?

Answer (score 10):

> In your options set multiTooltipTemplate to "<%=datasetLabel%> : <%= value %>" to do this.

From this Github issue : https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/535