# How to add dataset legend in chartjs tooltip

Tags: charts, chart.js

I'm using the chartjs to draw radar graphic. In the regular chartjs, the tooltip show the chartjs legend and underneath, the list of values  for this legend id.

Like :

**Eating**

- 65
- 28

I would like to add the dataset legend asoociated. (i this this shuld be possible since, there is the dataset color before the data

So i would like something like :

**Eating**

- 65 : My First dataset
- 28 : My Second dataset

I have [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zn6seqr8/6/) for the data

i think this has something to do with the tooltipTemplate option:

```
tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>"
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble, i should have search deeper  :

this is how you can do it : [How put dataset labels into multiTooltipTemplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278167/how-put-dataset-labels-into-multitooltiptemplate)