# Add some Text Inside of the Tooltip

Tags: chart.js

Goal:
When I have the cursor to display the tooltip I would like add the name of the month and then you display numbers

Problem:
I don't know how to do it in Chartjs version 1

Info:

- The X angle is Date
- Please remember that the name of the month would be changing based on user's selection from dropdownlist. The month is dynamical. In order to make the data to be dynamical I have the data inside of a input box and the n It will be sent tto Chart JS.
- If possible to show the solution inside of JSBin or JSfiddle.
- http://jsbin.com/mofeqavicu/edit?html,output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but the labels are defined in the array

```
labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

that you can change to

```
labels: ['Label 1','Label 2','Label 3','Label 4','Label 5','Label 6', 'Label 7', 8, 9, 10]
```

You can also define an array of labels to use in the `displayLineChart`.

```js
var myLabels = ['Label 1','Label 2','Label 3','Label 4','Label 5','Label 6', 'Label 7', 8, 9, 10];

  function displayLineChart() {
    var data = {
      labels: myLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
      }, {
        label: "Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
      }]
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
    var options = {};
    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>


<body onload="displayLineChart();">
  <div class="box">
    <canvas id="lineChart" height="450" width="800"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**: to manipulate the text in the tooltip you can define a template in the options for the chart. You have possibilities:

1. `multiTooltipTemplate` for multiple datasets
2. `tooltipTemplate` for single datasets

For `multiTooltipTemplate` it's not possible to change the title of the tooltip,if you want to do so you need to define your own custom tooltip.
This is because `multiTooltipTemplate` by default takes as a tooltip title the label of the x-axis.

(sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28579665/2314737 and https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/499)

Below is an example for a single dataset:

```js
var myLabels = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

  function displayLineChart() {
    var data = {
      labels: myLabels,
      datasets: [{
        label: "First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
        pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
        pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
      },]
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
    // define multiTooltip template
    var options = {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "My Text <%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>",   
    // tooltipTemplate is activated only when there's just one dataset
    tooltipTemplate: "Label <%= label %>",
    };
    
    var lineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, options);
    
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js"></script>

<body onload="displayLineChart();">
  <div class="box">
    <canvas id="lineChart" height="450" width="800"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I would like to have the number in the column to display only and when you have the cursor of the graph then you display the number with the text "Label". I don't want the text "Label" to display in the column. Only number shall be visible in the column. Please tell if you need more information!