# Format Bar Chart's yAxis labels in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, label, chart.js

I have looked the documentation and similar questions here but I don't seem to find a working solution to my problem.

I'm using Chart.js v.2.1.6, and I have a Bar Chart with percentage values stored as numbers (already multiplied by 100). I need both y-axis labels and tooltips to display the `%` sign after the values.

Someone can shed some light on that matter?

Here you have my code:

```
var data = {
  "labels": ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5"],
  "datasets": [{
    "label": "Variation",
    "data": ["56", "-82.3", "25.7", "32.2", "49.99"],
    "borderWidth": 1,
    "backgroundColor": "rgba(231, 76, 60, 0.2)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)"
  }]
};

var myBarChart = new Chart($("#myCanvas"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  maintainAspectRatio: false
});
```

And a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tdjk3ncs/

**EDIT: SOLVED**

I found the solution thanks to miquelarranz, find the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tdjk3ncs/7/

Comment: Have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568773/javascript-chart-js-custom-data-formatting-to-display-on-tooltip

Comment: @SanKrish I did, I included `tooltipTemplate` and `multiTooltipTemplate` options as they mention but I didn't seem to work in my case... Maybe that only works with Line Chart, and not Bar Chart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add `%`after the values of the Y-Axis you can do it using scales in your chart configuration. Your code will look like this:

```
var myBarChart = new Chart($("#myCanvas"), {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Create scientific notation labels
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return value + ' %';
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

[Documentation about scales](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-common-configuration)

Fiddle updated with the `%`: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdjk3ncs/6/)

And if you want to modify the text displayed in the tooltips you can easily change it using callback. You can find more information here [Tooltip Callbacks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-tooltip-configuration)

Comment: this even solved what scaleLabel failed to as I tried to do the same as shown http://jsfiddle.net/6xV78/294/ but since it looks like that was for chartjs 1.0 instead of 2.0 I guess more things have changed but I could just use the If statements in the callback and it worked fine.