# Adding prefix or suffix like $ to data labels in plugins in react-chartjs-2

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

1. Any idea of adding prefix like $ to add before data labels in "chartjs-plugins-datalbels" .
2. Any idea to move the datalabels to left or right on top of the bar on barchart in "chartjs-plugins-datalbels" .

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format Bar Chart's yAxis labels in Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180421/format-bar-charts-yaxis-labels-in-chart-js)

Answer (score 0):

```
const option ={
plugins: {
  tooltip: {
    callbacks: {
      label: (item) =>
        `${item.label}: ${item.formattedValue}`,
    },
  },
```

}
}