# MultiTooltip ng2-Charts & Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have a chart that has two lines draw on it. I want that when I hover on one point of either of the two lines, the little tooltip box shows the value of both points at that x point. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually have this same problem (I'm using ng2-charts 1.6.0/chart.js 2.6.0 with Angular 4) and according to this [Github post](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2379), you need to add the `mode: 'label'` to the options config. Here's my final options for my line chart:

```
{ 
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: true,
  multiTooltipTemplate: '<%= datasetLabel %> - <%= value %>',
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'label'
  }
};
```

And I now have a tooltip that looks like this:

```
January
Bob - xx
Tina - xx
```

Similar/related SO post: [chart-js-multitooltip-labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510278/chart-js-multitooltip-labels)

Comment: it works but you need to set `maintainAspectRatio` to `true`

Comment: @GPecchio Edited as suggested. Thanks.