# Chartjs bar dataset label not showing

Tags: chart.js

Trying to compare this year vs last year on bar chart and labels for dataset "this year" & "previous year" are not showing. This thing is specially handy when comparing multiple datasets side by side so any help is greatly appreciated.
By the way my chartjs version is 2.1.4

```
  var chartdata = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      // labels: month,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'this year',
          backgroundColor: '#26B99A',
          data: sold1
        },
        {
          label: 'previous year',
          backgroundColor: '#03586A',
          data: sold2
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Comment: Check this thread if you still need an answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510278/chart-js-multitooltip-labels

Answer (score 13):

Set autoSkip for xAxis to false :

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
      beginAtZero: true,
      ticks: {
         autoSkip: false
      }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your `sold1` and `sold2`.

```
console.log(sold1);
console.log(sold2);
```

For example this is working:

```
var chartdata = {
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
          // labels: month,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'this year',
              backgroundColor: '#26B99A',
              data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
            },
            {
              label: 'previous year',
              backgroundColor: '#03586A',
              data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
            }
          ]
        }
    }
};



var ctx = document.getElementById('chartContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, chartdata);
```

**JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/1davgzmh/1/

Comment: Thanks for help Alex! Checked console again and both output seems to be correct.:

Comment: sold1 output (11) ["357508.03", "393790.14", "407346.07", "557704.12", "555916.68", "422659.26", "297766.49", "448256.07", "510020.86", "325525.30", "89214.27"]

Comment: sold2 output (11) ["409550.01", "396759.48", "337295.41", "404729.91", "298772.12", "455665.55", "411476.19", "403140.82", "452218.70", "390890.12", "512817.69"]

Comment: and if i to datas like data: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13] still get no label. very strange

Comment: Check the JSFiddle, I can't do more than a JSFiddle working example with the partial code you posted.

Comment: Yep checked JSFiddle few times all seems to be correct.

Comment: Make sure `chartdata` is defined before you call `new Chart(ctx, chartdata);`

Comment: Yep chartdata is defined before call checked that too. Tried round up decimals and still the same. If I make standalone chart on seperate file however label show up no problem!

Comment: What can I say, keep debugging, start new, add things one at a time.

Comment: Yep will try one at a time and see how it solve the problem. Thanks again for all your help mate!

Answer (score 1):

this is working for me. Try youself

```
var chartdata = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'this year',
                    backgroundColor: '#26B99A',
                    data: sold1
                },
                {
                    label: 'previous year',
                    backgroundColor: '#03586A',
                    data: sold2
                }
            ]
        },
        "options": {
            "legend": {"position": "bottom"},
            "scales": {
                "xAxes": [
                    {
                        "beginAtZero": true,
                        "ticks": {
                            "autoSkip": false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    };
```